# Modular double of elliptic quantum group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, integrable-systems

By studying dynamical quantum Yang-Baxter equations and corresponding $RLL$ relations, Felder defined an elliptic version of quantum group $E_{\tau, \eta}(sl_2)$, which can be understood as $\mathfrak{h}-$Hopf algebroid.

There is a standard construction given by Faddeev, that the quantum group $U_q(sl_2)$ can be doubled, by introducing the new modular parameter ${\tilde q}$.

My question is, does Felder's quantum group $E_{\tau, \eta}(sl_2)$ have modular double structure?